# Different way of writing this SQL query with partition

Tags: sql, teradata

Hi I have the below query in Teradata. I have a row number partition and from that I want rows with rn=1. Teradata doesn't let me use the row number as a filter in the same query. I know that I can put the below into a subquery with a `where rn=1` and it gives me what I need. But the below snippet needs to go into a larger query and I want to simplify it if possible.

Is there a different way of doing this so I get a table with 2 columns - one row per customer with the corresponding fc_id for the latest eff_to_dt?

```
select cust_grp_id, fc_id, row_number() over (partition by cust_grp_id order by eff_to_dt desc) as rn
from table1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the QUALIFY clause in your query?

```
SELECT cust_grp_id
     , fc_id
  FROM table1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() 
              OVER (PARTITION BY cust_grp_id 
                    ORDER BY eff_to_dt desc)
      = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate `MAX` `eff_to_dt` for each `cust_grp_id` and then join result to main table.

```
SELECT T1.cust_grp_id,
       T1.fc_id,
       T1.eff_to_dt
FROM Table1 AS T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT cust_grp_id,
           MAX(eff_to_dt) AS max_eff_to_dt
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY cust_grp_id) AS T2 ON T2.cust_grp_id = T1.cust_grp_id
                                    AND T2.max_eff_to_dt = T1.eff_to_dt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pair of `JOIN`s to accomplish the same thing:

```
INNER JOIN My_Table T1 ON <some criteria>
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T2 ON <some criteria> AND T2.eff_to_date > T1.eff_to_date
WHERE
    T2.my_id IS NULL
```

You'll need to sort out the specific criteria for your larger query, but this is effectively `JOIN`ing all of the rows (T1), but then excluding any where a later row exists. In the `WHERE` clause you eliminate these by checking for a NULL value in a column that is `NOT NULL` (in this case I just assumed some ID value). The only way that would happen is if the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on T2 failed to find a match - i.e. no rows later than the one that you want exist.

Also, whether or not the `JOIN` to T1 is `LEFT OUTER` or `INNER` is up to your specific requirements.